# Moodle Database Connection Failed

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, moodle

> Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'moodledude'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /var/www/html/moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line
>   79

How can i solve this issue? Could anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: Seems that the password is invalid or missing for the given user

Comment: https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Errors_FAQ#Error:_database_connection_failed

Answer (score 0):

Can u please check the config.php file inside moodle folder

```
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = '';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = '<URL>';
```

OR please check the table `mdl_user`

Please check the config file for db connection failure

Comment: yes thanks ...I changed to root